# GWT application doesn't terminate from within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

When I try to terminate my GWT based web application from within Eclipse , it fails to terminate the java process and a popup appears saying "Terminate Failed". Now , I have to open up the activity monitor each time I terminate my application and "**force quit**" the java process. Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

I am running:

- Mac OSX 10.5
- Eclipse Indigo(3.7)
- GWT 2.2
- JDK 1.6_029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when my backend code performed task which extremely used the processor, so it was unavailable to eclipse runner. Try to terminate new sample GWT project. Also you can restart the server instead shutdown by pressing the 'Restart' buton wich is nearby 'Stop' button.